# Angular Delete http request

Tags: angular

I'm getting started with angular CRUD operation and I want to have this delete request. My problem is When I execute this delete request on whichever rows I want to delete, It's always the first row.
my Html-

```
 <tr *ngFor="let users of RegisteredUserList">
        <td>{{users.id}}</td>
        <td>{{users.userName}}</td>
        <td>{{users.email}}</td>
        <td>
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-danger mr-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteModal">Delete</button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="DeleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="DeleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="DeleteModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Do you really want to delete {{users.userName}}.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-danger mr-1" (click)="Delete(users.id)">Save changes</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

my component.ts -

```
Delete(id: string): void {
    this.service.DeleteUser(id).subscribe(
      (data) => console.log("Success") );
  }
```

myservice.ts -

```
DeleteUser(id: string): Observable<any> {
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }
    return this.http.delete<any>(this.baseURL + "Account/Delete" + "/" + id, options);
  }
```

backend code-

```
[Route("~/Account/Delete/{id?}")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromBody] string id)
        {
            var findUser = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (findUser != null)
            {
                var deleteUser = await userManager.DeleteAsync(findUser);
                if (deleteUser.Succeeded)
                {
                    return StatusCode(200);
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

which ever row I try to delete, only the first row is being sent and 400 error is thrown.

Comment: Did you check if the right ID is being sent ? if it does , can you show us your backend side ?

Comment: @BarLevin Hi. No,whichever button I click, only the first row Id is being sent.

Comment: you are creating a modal with the same id for each row

Comment: Thank you @Munzer. I've solved it.